# If I change my DNS's IP address will that change the Google Compute instance instantly?

Tags: google, dns, ip-address, google-compute

I'm currently using Google Compute to host my website.

If I change the IP address under Google Cloud DNS will that change the instance instantly?

Upgrading Instance Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XYUeORywXU

Or will it be delayed, like with nameserver propagation?

**UPDATE:**

I have created a "clone", using a Snapshot, with the new machine specifications and hard disk size I am looking for.

- I have checked my FTP and it works - all my php files etc are there.
- I have checked my phpmyadmin and it is working and all tables are
  intact.

However, when I access the ip address in my browser it does not load the page. Does this simply mean I need to update my DNS IP Address to point to the new instance? Will this switchover be instant?

I'm trying to figure out really if the DNS IP address is something I can switch at a second's notice or if I play with it I could be disrupting my pathroute for days...

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a clear process to upgrade my compute server without service disruption of more than 30 minutes :)

Comment: [This Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327973) suggests stopping, editing the type, and restarting the instance. Will that do? It should take well under 30 minutes.

Comment: @TomBrossman is it safe to stop the instance though? I feel really worried about this whole thing because I'm a php/mysqli/css/javascript specialist and my knowledge about hosting/servers is really limited. It's scary :(

Comment: I also want to upgrade my hard disk for more capacity. Will I be able to do that as well when up upgrade by stopping? How do I do that?

Comment: Hmmm, it will let me create a clone? Is that how I upgrade (including my disk capacity)?

Comment: Answering this question is difficult because it is a mix of several different issues. 1) Changing DNS is slow - it takes hours to propagate so avoid doing so if possible. 2) Stopping your instance should not break anything, it's just like rebooting your computer. 3) Any edits to the machine type and disk size should be possible with it temporarily shut down. 4) As a paying customer of a product, have you tried opening a support ticket asking how best to upgrade while minimising down-time? This would be the best course of action. Switch providers if they won't help you.

Comment: Sadly they charge extra for support. I emailed them for pricing.....they are yet to get back to me....

Comment: Personally, I'd be long gone already. Here's how to accomplish your goal at two of their primary competitors. [Resize an Amazon EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) and [Resize a DigitalOcean Droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-resize-your-droplets-on-digitalocean). This is a good time to browse the documentation of a few different providers, the support policies, and think about switching before you encounter even more difficult situations.

Comment: What you get, if you ping the port 80 and nslookup of domain name?

Answer (score 2):

I use Route53 which is amazons version. I can relate that I have a 60 second TTL on all my zones and when I make a change, that change syncs to their dns infrastructure in about 10 seconds. All total when I change a record with them and sync its about 2 minutes.

To affect a change to a single server I would

1. Change or ensure ttl is at 60s.
2. Verify that change has propogated. DIG. Old TTL plus New TTL = propogation time to first tiers.
3. Once I see that change has propogated, then I know its just 60s to a record change.
4. Create second record set for change to be made. TTL 60s
5. wait a min, do the switch.

This is why I leave my TTL at 60, that and Amazons managed DNS is essentially doing l3 routing based on geo and latency for me.